# Find the Pay Begin Date associated with the minimum Pay Period

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, bi-publisher

I am working with BI Publisher Desktop and using data from Oracle PeopleSoft.

What I need to do: 
Find the minimum E.PAY_PERIOD and show the E.PAY_BEGIN_DT associated with this pay period.

I have an XML file that looks similar to this:

```
<row rownumber="535">
    <C.OTH_HRS>-100.0</C.OTH_HRS>
    <C.OTH_EARNS>-1000.00</C.OTH_EARNS>
    <C.ERNCD><![CDATA[WCB]]></C.ERNCD>
    <D.DESCR><![CDATA[Workers Compensation]]></D.DESCR>
    <B.PAY_END_DT>2017-08-29</B.PAY_END_DT>
    <E.PAY_BEGIN_DT>2017-08-16</E.PAY_BEGIN_DT>
    <E.PAY_END_DT>2017-08-29</E.PAY_END_DT>
    <B.EMPLID><![CDATA[99999]]></B.EMPLID>
    <B.NAME><![CDATA[LastName,FirstName]]></B.NAME>
    <F.UNION_CD><![CDATA[7]]></F.UNION_CD>
    <E.PAY_PERIOD><![CDATA[3]]></E.PAY_PERIOD>
</row>

<row rownumber="536">
    <C.OTH_HRS>0</C.OTH_HRS>
    <C.OTH_EARNS>-10.00</C.OTH_EARNS>
    <C.ERNCD><![CDATA[052]]></C.ERNCD>
    <D.DESCR><![CDATA[Adjustment to sick pay (15%)]]></D.DESCR>
    <B.PAY_END_DT>2017-09-12</B.PAY_END_DT>
    <E.PAY_BEGIN_DT>2017-08-30</E.PAY_BEGIN_DT>
    <E.PAY_END_DT>2017-09-12</E.PAY_END_DT>
    <B.EMPLID><![CDATA[99998]]></B.EMPLID>
    <B.NAME><![CDATA[LastName,FirstName]]></B.NAME>
    <F.UNION_CD><![CDATA[7]]></F.UNION_CD>
    <E.PAY_PERIOD><![CDATA[1]]></E.PAY_PERIOD>
</row>
```

In my XML file there are 1333 rows. Rows numbered 1 to 535 have E.PAY_PERIOD equal to 3, and rows numbered 536 to 1333 have E.PAY_PERIOD equal to 1. When E.PAY_PERIOD is equal to 3, B.PAY_BEGIN_DT is equal to 2017-08-16 for rows 1 to 535, and when E.PAY_PERIOD is equal to 1, B.PAY_BEGIN_DT is equal to 2017-08-30 for rows 536 to 1333.

What I am trying to do is find the minimun E.PAY_PERIOD and when found show the associated B.PAY_BEGIN_DT. This date is needed on a report and I only need to show it one time.

This is what I have been work with:

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘minPayPeriod’, xdoxslt:minimum(E.PAY_PERIOD))?>

<?choose:?>
<?when:xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘minPayPeriod’)?>
      minPayPeriod: <?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘minPayPeriod’)?>
      E.PAY_BEGIN_DT: <?E.PAY_BEGIN_DT?>
      E.PAY_END_DT: <?E.PAY_END_DT?>
<?end when?>
<?end choose?>
```

The output of this is:

```
minPayPeriod: 1 <-- this is correct
E.PAY_BEGIN_DT: 2017-08-16 <-- I need this date to be 2017-08-30 since this is the date when E.PAY_PERIOD is 1.
E.PAY_END_DT: 2017-08-29 <-- I need this date to be 2017-09-12 since this is the date when E.PAY_PERIOD is 1.
```

Also, how can I tell which row number E.PAY_BEGIN_DT and E.PAY_END_DT are from.

I hope I've explained this properly.

Thanks for any help.

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the minimum value, you will have to search the XML for the node containing that value, and print its corresponding date. Here is some pseducode, I (haven't tested it).

```
<?choose:?>
<?when:xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘minPayPeriod’)?>
      minPayPeriod: <?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘minPayPeriod’)?>
      E.PAY_BEGIN_DT: <?row [E.PAY_PERIOD = xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘minPayPeriod’)]/[0]/E.PAY_BEGIN_DT?>
      E.PAY_END_DT:  <?row [E.PAY_PERIOD = xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘minPayPeriod’)]/[0]/E.PAY_END_DT?>
<?end when?>
<?end choose?>
```

The /[0] part is to search for the first occurrence, instead of printing all matches.

Comment: I used this, or something very similar to fix the issue. Unfortunately, do to PeopleSoft not allowing sub-templates to have connected data sources, we had to look into another solution, and this report was put on hold due to time constraints. But thank you very much for your feedback. I learned quite a bit while working on this report - it does work on my computer, just not in PeopleSoft.